# Ubuntu 14.04 stuck in login loop

Tags: login-screen

I installed the cuda toolkit 7 and right after I restarted I was stuck in a login loop. I tried all the suggestions I could find which includes deleting the .Xauthority file, .profile, reconfiguring lightdm, reinstalling lightdm, checking ownership permissions etc.

Nothing worked, my only option seems to be a reinstall, however, since I'm not sure what caused this in the first place I'm thinking it may quite well occur again.

Any suggestions outside the aforementioned is most welcome. I really just need to be able to login so that I can get to my work, thanks.